# Is there any way to set a suffix into a env variable with convict?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to refactor old code to manage env variables to convict, the problem is that I have the following case:

**Old code**

```
  {
    indexAlias: process.env.ES_INDEX ? `${process.env.ES_INDEX}_sw` : "",
  }
```

**Convict code**

```
esIndex: {
    doc: "",
    format: String,
    env: "ES_INDEX",
    default: "",
  }
```

The problem here is there are other ES_INDEX references with other suffixes and a lot of cross dependencies with that env variable in CI/CD applications, so instead of changing that env variable in all infrastructure or creating a lot, one for each suffix, I would like to know if there is any way of setting a suffix to convict?

Comment: could you please provide more context? what type do yuo expect?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using addFormat like a new type

```
var convict = require('convict');

convict.addFormat({
    name: 'sw-suffix',
    validate: function(val) {
        if (!(val instanceof "string")) {
          throw new Error('must be a string');
        }
      },
    coerce: (val) => {
      return `${val}_sf`;
    }
  });
  
var config = convict({
    space_used: {
        format: 'sw-suffix',
        default: "aaa"
    }
});

console.log(config.get('space_used')) // aaa_sw
```